What is the Kronecker product of two 1D vectors?
When working with $n$-qubit systems, we can use the Kronecker product $\otimes$ to build corresponding bigger Hilbert spaces. For example:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix} \otimes  \begin{bmatrix} \gamma \\ \delta \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha\gamma  \\ \alpha \delta  \\ \beta\gamma \\ \beta \delta  \end{bmatrix},$$
and we can keep building up from that. However, I was wondering if it is possible to write $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}$ as a Kronecker product itself? Intuitively I'd write something like $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \end{bmatrix} \otimes  \begin{bmatrix} \beta \end{bmatrix}$, although if I use the formal definition then the result would be $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \beta \end{bmatrix}$, which is still a $1\times1$ matrix and not what I expect. I can hand-wavily say that when when I'm building a bigger Hilbert space out of $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} \beta \end{bmatrix}$, they each need to go on a different dimension because each one lives on its own Hilbert space, but how do I justify that mathematically?

I would be inclined to think this is not well defined. Think the dimension of the resulting vector in your case is $d=2$. According to the Kronecker product rule, you would need to construct such vector from $\sqrt{2}$ dimensional vectors (?), which is not defined.

The tensor product of $\mathbb C^m$ and $\mathbb C^n$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb C^{mn}$. Therefore, if you're asking the reverse question it becomes a matter of factoring numbers. In your case your target space is $\mathbb C^2$ and there are, obviously, only two ways to factor the number two: $2\cdot 1$ and $1\cdot 2$. Therefore, the only ways to build your target space are:
$$
\mathbb C^2=\mathbb C^2\otimes\mathbb C^1\quad\text{ and }\quad\mathbb C^2=\mathbb C^1\otimes\mathbb C^2
$$
In particular, there is no non-trivial way of decomposing $\mathbb C^2$ because $2$ is a prime number.

It is possible to do this, but not in a nontrivial way:
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\ 
\beta 
\end{bmatrix}
&= \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha \\ 
\beta 
\end{bmatrix}\otimes 
\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
This agrees with the answer of @frederik-vom-ende.
